# Specify custom message from mock verification in PHPUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, assertion

We can customise the message of an assertion like this:

```
$this->assertEquals(true, false, 'should be equal');
```

I have a mock object:

```
$mockExecutionContext = $this->getMock('some interface');
$mockExecutionContext->expects($this->once())->method('someMethod');
```

How can I customise the message displayed when this gets verified?

Comment: The [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects) says "Only mock objects generated within the scope of a test will be verified automatically by PHPUnit."  Perhaps I can use manual verification for the custom message, but I cannot find anything about manual assertion.

Comment: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1509